# How to expand Jquery Slider Panel programatically?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-2.0

I have JQuery Silder panel for Login | Register option. for referencing i have include demo of this slider [Jquery Login | Register Slider Panel](http://web-kreation.com/tutorials/nice-clean-sliding-login-panel-built-with-jquery/)

the actually problem was how to expand programatically this slider when located Literal control have value in Login Section or Register New account section. for understanding this problem i putting my design code.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Login_Register" runat="server" CssClass="Panel_Slide">
    <div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Welcome" runat="server" CssClass="left">
                <h1>Welcome to Om Investment</h1>
                <p class="grey">Om Investment Stock Market Research Trading &amp; Advisory, the most successful market
                trading team and has predicted the market direction always ahead of others, our
                powerful and high volume Market Gains trading team will deliver high returns to
                the Capital invested by clients, We have a consistent success ratio genuine more than
                80% in every type of Market.</p>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Login" runat="server" CssClass="left" Width="200px" DefaultButton="btnlogin">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Username:" CssClass="grey" AssociatedControlID="txtusername"></asp:Label>
                      <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtusername" WatermarkText="Enter username here"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="Login"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Username is required.</span>"
                                                ControlToValidate="txtusername" ValidationGroup="Login" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
                                                Width="200px" HighlightCssClass="highlight" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png"
                                                CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif">
                                            </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Password:" CssClass="grey" AssociatedControlID="txtpassword"></asp:Label>
                     <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender12" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpassword"
                                                WatermarkText="123456789"/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="Login" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Password is required.</span>"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtpassword" ValidationGroup="Login" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
                                                Width="200px" HighlightCssClass="highlight" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png"
                                                CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif">
                                            </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender><br />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_remember" runat="server"/>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Remeber Me ?" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="bt_login" ValidationGroup="Login" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" />
                    <a class="lost-pwd" href="password_recover.aspx"> Lost your password ?</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p class="grey"><asp:Literal ID="ltr_error" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
            </asp:Panel>
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Register" runat="server" CssClass="left right" DefaultButton="btn_register" Width="356px">            
                    <h1>Create New Account</h1>             
      <p class="grey">(All the fields are compulsory)</p>
           <table><tr><td><asp:Label id="Label6" runat="server" Text="Your Name*" AssociatedControlID="txtname" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label> <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender5" watermarkText="Enter your name" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtname">
              </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender> <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtname" ValidChars=" ,." FilterType="UppercaseLetters,LowercaseLetters,Custom">
              </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender></td></tr>
              <tr><td><asp:TextBox id="txtname" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your name is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                        </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>                                      
            <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label7" runat="server" Text="Your Username*" AssociatedControlID="txtusername1" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label> <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender6" watermarkText="Enter your username" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtusername1">
            </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender> <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtusername" FilterType="UppercaseLetters,LowercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom">
              </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender></td></tr>
             <tr><td><asp:TextBox id="txtusername1" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtusername1" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="SignUp" CssClass="grey" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Gray'>Username is already exist</span>"></asp:CustomValidator></td></tr>
             <tr><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtusername1" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your username is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender7" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator6" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                      </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
             <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label9" runat="server" Text="Your Account Password*" AssociatedControlID="txtpass" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label> <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpass" ValidChars="." FilterType="UppercaseLetters,LowercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" InvalidChars=" ,'">
              </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender> <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender7" watermarkText="1234567890" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpass">
            </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:TextBox id="txtpass" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="15" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> <cc1:PasswordStrength id="PasswordStrength1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpass" RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="false" MinimumSymbolCharacters="0" MinimumNumericCharacters="0" StrengthStyles="TextIndicator_TextBox1_Strength1;TextIndicator_TextBox1_Strength2;TextIndicator_TextBox1_Strength3;TextIndicator_TextBox1_Strength4;TextIndicator_TextBox1_Strength5" TextStrengthDescriptions="Very Poor;Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent" HelpStatusLabelID="TextBox1_HelpLabel" PrefixText="Strength:" PreferredPasswordLength="10" StrengthIndicatorType="Text" DisplayPosition="RightSide"></cc1:PasswordStrength> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtpass" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your account password is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender8" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator7" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label10" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password*" AssociatedControlID="txtcpass" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label><cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender8" watermarkText="1234567890" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtcpass">
            </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender> <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtpass" ValidChars="." FilterType="UppercaseLetters,LowercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" InvalidChars=" ,'">
              </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:TextBox id="txtcpass" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="15" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtcpass" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Confirm password is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtcpass" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Entered Field is Invalid</b><br />Your new password and confirm password doesn't mathched.</span>" ControlToCompare="txtpass"></asp:CompareValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender9" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator8" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender11" runat="server" TargetControlID="CompareValidator1" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
          <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label12" runat="server" Text="Your Birth Date*" AssociatedControlID="txtbdate" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label> <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender10" watermarkText="Enter your birthdate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtbdate">
          </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender></td></tr>
          <tr><td><asp:TextBox id="txtbdate" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp"></asp:TextBox> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtbdate" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your birthdate is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtbdate" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Entered Field is Invalid</b><br/>Birth date format should be like: DD/MM/yyyy</span>" ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> <cc1:CalendarExtender id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtbdate" PopupButtonID="img_cal" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
              </cc1:CalendarExtender> <cc1:MaskedEditExtender id="MaskedEditExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtbdate" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" AcceptNegative="Left" DisplayMoney="Left" MaskType="Date" OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" MessageValidatorTip="true" Mask="99/99/9999"></cc1:MaskedEditExtender> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender13" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator10" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender14" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator3" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
          <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label11" runat="server" Text="Your e-mail*" AssociatedControlID="txtemail" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label><cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender9" watermarkText="Enter your email" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtemail">
          </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender></td></tr>
          <tr>
          <td><asp:TextBox id="txtemail" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" ControlToValidate="txtemail" SetFocusOnError="true" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate" CssClass="grey" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Gray'>Email is already exist</span>"></asp:CustomValidator></td></tr>
          <tr><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your email is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtemail" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Entered Field is Invalid</b><br/>Email format should be like: name@domain.com</span>" ValidationExpression="^[\w-\.]{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,6}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender10" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator9" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender12" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator2" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
          <tr><td><asp:Label id="Label13" runat="server" Text="Your Phone no*" AssociatedControlID="txtphoneno" CssClass="grey"></asp:Label> <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender id="TextBoxWatermarkExtender11" watermarkText="Enter your phone no" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtphoneno">
          </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender> <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender6" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtphoneno" FilterType="Numbers">
              </cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender></td></tr>
          <tr>
          <td><asp:TextBox id="txtphoneno" runat="server" CssClass="field" ValidationGroup="SignUp" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox><asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" ControlToValidate="txtphoneno" SetFocusOnError="true" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator3_ServerValidate" CssClass="grey" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Gray'>Phone no is already exist</span>"></asp:CustomValidator></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtphoneno" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Required Field Missing</b><br />Your phone no is required.</span>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SignUp" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtphoneno" ErrorMessage="<span style='color:Black'><b>Entered Field is Invalid</b><br/>Phone no format should like : 9000000098<br/> +91 Not Needed<span>" ValidationExpression="^((\\+91-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender15" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator11" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender> <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender id="ValidatorCalloutExtender16" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator4" Width="200px" CloseImageUrl="images/close.gif" WarningIconImageUrl="images/1329542890_dialog-warning.png" HighlightCssClass="highlight">
                                                       </cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender></td></tr>
           <tr><td><asp:Button ID="btn_register" runat="server" Text="Register" ValidationGroup="SignUp" CssClass="bt_register" OnClick="btn_register_Click"/></td></tr>
          </table>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p class="grey"><asp:Literal ID="ltr_message2" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
         </asp:Panel>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello Guest!</li><li class="sep">|</li><li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Log In | Register</a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

this slider works fine but i have no idea to how to auto expand this panel if one of the Literal have value.

In Register New Account panel i have also custome validators also i have to found the way  to expand this panel if one the three custome validator throws Error message.

For details referencing i have also include js/slide.js file content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");

    }); 

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });     

    // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });     

});
```

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*Updated Code*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
this code is about how i append my custome error to literal control

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = Util.GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckUserAccount", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtusername.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpassword.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Error", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Return Value", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int returnValue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@Return Value"].Value;
            if (returnValue == 1)
            {
                if (chk_remember.Checked == true)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_Read_User_Type", conn);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Id"));
                    cmd1.Parameters["@Userid"].Value = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader["Type_name"].ToString() == "Admin")
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txtusername.Text;
                            Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txtpassword.Text;
                            Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                            Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                            Session["username"] = reader["Id"].ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_page.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txtusername.Text;
                            Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txtpassword.Text;
                            Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                            Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                            Session["username"] = reader["Id"].ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/myhome.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    conn.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp_Read_User_Type", conn);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Id"));
                    cmd1.Parameters["@Userid"].Value = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader["Type_name"].ToString() == "Admin")
                        {
                            Session["username"] = reader["Id"].ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_page.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session["username"] = reader["Id"].ToString();
                            Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/myhome.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ltr_error.Text = (string)cmd.Parameters["@Error"].Value;                                        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated version:**
Literal doesn't generate any tag on page. Therefore you need to set id for

tag that wrap your Literal. (or something more suitable for you)

```
<p id="p_error" class="grey"><asp:Literal ID="ltr_error" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
```

After that you can use js for check any text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#p_error").text() != "") //choose condition more suitable for you
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: i have added text to literal control after post back by click event of this Image Button in asp.net 2.0 with c#. is there is way to check literal control value sated after post back in Jquery.

Comment: If you use just asp.net without ajax, $(document).ready(...); will be triggered after your postback.

Comment: I 'm using ur code in MasterPage in <script type="text/javascript"></script> but it always expand my panel while page load.

Comment: You could try to add breakpoints to all slideDown lines at js script in DevelperTool of your's browser and checked value that is returned by $('#<%= ltr_message2.ClientID %>').val(), after that you can try to fix condition. Don't forget to replace the <%= ltr_message2.ClientID %> with id from page source.

Comment: can u give me full soln about how i include ur code into my slide.js file.

Comment: I can give advice only when I see your project. I have no more ideas without sources.

Comment: Nice, accept the answer (mark with a green tick), please. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

http://www.roorkichap.com/sliding-login-panel-built-with-jquery-asp-net-vb-net-and-sql-server-2000/
download the source code and check out